# Stuck on "Finished casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums."

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-installation, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I tried to run a Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon Edition vm in Hyper-V, but I've had some problems.

When I used the Gen 2 option, it always displayed `>>Start PXE over IPv4`.

When I installed using Gen 1, it immediately went to a fully black screen.
Then I tried installing the compatibility mode (also in Gen 1), which started normal, but got stuck at:

```
[  OK  ] Finished casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums.
```

Does this mean my ISO is corrupt? I'm confused because it says `[  OK  ]`.

#### EDIT:

I verified the ISO with the checksum again and everyting matches perfectly.

#### Additional info:

- VM RAM: 16GiB (16384MiB)
- VM STORAGE: 127GiB
- VM Cores: 4
- VM Gen: 1
- Hyper-V Conf Version: 11.0